# Need help understanding RIGHT Padding in syncsort

Tags: mainframe, syncsort

I am using SyncSort to format a file. My requirement is to add RIGHT padding (trailing spaces to a field). Can you please suggest how to do this?

For Example:-

```
Value :- "15" ---> Output:- "15   "
Value :- "150" --> Output:- "150  "
```

Comment: I have given you an answer for variable-length input records containing your example digits. I suspect that this is not your actual data, but I have no real clue. You have updated your question with something that you should already get as your output if you run the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
INREC IFOUTLEN=9,
      IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT,OVERLAY=10:X)
```

You question does not really make sense in isolation. Either this is a small part of a larger task, and so may not suit, or you have a VB file with no *trailing* blanks. Or something else.

Unless you have a simple VB with just one field, in which case this code will work, please add what you have tried and what output it gave you.